# Titanium Runtime error : Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: analytics.google

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-modules

[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [156,156] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,156] - In ti:/module.js:303,2
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,156] - Message: Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: analytics.google
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,156] - Source:         throw new Error('Requested module not found: ' + request); // TODO Set 'code' property to 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' to match Node?
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at ti:/module.js:303: Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: analytics.google

I get the above error when running on Android emulator. I'm Using Ti SDK 7.0.0 and running on API level 23 emulator. 
I have even removed analytics.google module from TiApp.xml but still gives the same error.

[image]Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`analytics.google` is a module you have (or have not) included in your application. If by "I removed it" you mean you've excluded it from `tiapp.xml` then you should also remove it from your code.

Somewhere in your code there should be `require('analytics.google')`

Also... starting with TiSDK 7.0.0.GA modules had to be recompiled. Looking at the [repository](https://github.com/Sitata/titanium-google-analytics) it looks like it hasn't been updated for 2 years. You can update the module yourself by using [this guide](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Android+Module+Upgrade+Guide) or move to a [better updated module](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Ti.GA)

Edit: I see the module has already been updated in a PR. You can use [that build](https://github.com/Sitata/titanium-google-analytics/pull/70) instead also